# How to display skip button for facebook Single Sign on?

Tags: android

I am using this method to allow the user to sign on to facebook at the beginning of the application, If they want.

```
package com.greatap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

If they dont want to then the can just press skip to continue using the app without signing in. Ive seen this in many applications. I dont see any instructions on the developer's page for facebook to implement this. 
Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why dont you create a dialog with a "Sign In" / "Skip" buttons to do this before showing the authentication iFrame?

Comment: Like just a Layout with two buttons... Sign on with facebook and the other Skip... Is this what you mean? Because the facebook dialog is launched when the activity is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Consider you created a dialog with two buttons "Log in" and "Skip"

Move this block of code:

```
    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
```

to the conditional:

```
if(userPressedLoginAndNotSkip){
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Thats exaclty what ill do.